# Compilar un programa en c

Tags: c

Teniendo en cuenta que los comando en linux (no se si todos) están escritos en c, me gustaría saber ¿Cómo hago para compilar un programa en c, en el que no necesite, para correrlo, colocarle al inicio "sh" o "./", tal como se hace para correr un comando (ejemplo: clear, ls, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Para ejecutar los programas como comandos tienes que añadirlos a la variable path. Puedes usar el siguiente comando:

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:/ruta/al/ejecutable
```

Despues de eso podras correlos sin el `./`